# why the go routine return different result when I change the order or the execution of two go routines that are the same?

Tags: go, goroutine

So if we switch the go routine order we get a different result. Why?
I added a screenshot with the output and the code.The code is the same in both go routines so it shouldn't change anithing.

```
func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    done := make(chan bool)
    sdone := make(chan bool)

    //run first go routine
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("Done one")
            case <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("Running one")
            }
        }
    }()

    //run second go routine
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-sdone:
                fmt.Println("Done second")

            case <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("running second")
            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    ticker.Stop()
    done <- true
    done <- true
    fmt.Println("Tickers stopped")
    //if we switch the order of the run the result is different
}
```

[image: go routine screenshot]

Comment: You have 2 concurrent goroutines receiving from the same channel. It's unspecified which one will receive the values occasional sent on them. The runtime may likely choose one that is waiting for a longer time, but this is not written in the spec and may change from version to version, platform to platform.

Comment: First code snippet doesn't set anything on `sdone` channel. You are setting data to `done` channel 2 times. It will never print `Done second`

Comment: Advice: look into context.WithCancel() or context.WithTimeout() to close the goroutines rather than using a close channel. It uses channels under the hood but is a lot harder to shoot yourself in the foot with compared to using a close channel.